# Need help to write elasticsearch query which should search based on text of one field and another array field with (passed values or null)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, logstash, kibana, fuzzy-search

I have data in the mysql database which have been stored into elasticsearch as documents using logstash job.

```
**Data example in database:**

firstname(text), lastname(text), email(text), tags(text & nullable)
```

Here, tags conains value as per this in mysql : "t1,t2,t3" or ""

While adding data into elasticsearch, custom analyzer/tokenizer has been applied using ",(comma)".

I need data as per this and need to write the query for this:

```
firstname = "text", tags = ["t1","t2"]

"Get all records which contain this firstname and tags with either "t1 or t2 or (t1 & t2) or null" (any in which tags are empty)".
```

I have tried a few queries to get this kind of result but nothing worked.
(It doesn't return records with null tags as well tags with (t1,t2))

```
GET /posts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "some_text",
                  "fields": [
                    "firstname^1.0"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "tags": [
                          "t2"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "some_text",
                  "fields": [
                    "firstname^1.0"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "tags": [
                          ""
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET /posts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "some_text",
                  "fields": [
                    "firstname^1.0"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "tags": [
                          "t2"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "some_text",
                  "fields": [
                    "firstname^1.0"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                   "must_not": {
                      "exists": {
                          "field": "tags"
                       }
                    }                
                 }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the null check (`nust_not` -> `exists`) inside the should clause along with the `terms` query for `tags`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "some_text",
            "fields": [
              "firstname^1.0"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "tags": [
              "t1",
              "t2",
              ""
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "tags"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

## OR

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "some_text",
            "fields": [
              "firstname^1.0"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "tags": [
                    "t1",
                    "t2",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "tags"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working properly. Let's say with firstname as milan 2 entries are there (one with tags as t1,t2 and another is with blank tags) then this query will give result 
but let's say if I change t2 to t3 in the above query then still it will return 2 records which is incorrect.

Comment: Update answer. `minimum_should_match` should do. Please check and let me know.

Comment: No, still not working with these new queries. It returns records which have t1/t2 but does not return records which have tags as empty

Comment: Are you considering `"tags" : [""]` as empty?

Comment: Yes, in elasticseach, it is showing me this way: "tags": [""]
Is it incorrect?

Comment: This will not be considered as empty. In such case you should handle that it doesn't get indexed in such a way. To handle it at query end add `""` along with other terms in `terms` query. But note that adding this will give you documents with tags value as `["t5", "t4", ""]` as well. So it is better to handle this during index time. Also note that `"tags": []` will be considered as empty.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you said. but it is confirmed that, documents will have either like this : tags : ["t4","t5"] or tags : [""]. it will not have as you mentioned like ["t5", "t4", ""]. Can you send query in that way?

Comment: Updated answer for the same.

Comment: Hey, @nishantsaini20 , your explanation helped me to understand data and your queries guide me to find correct query for my use-cases. Actually, tags should be like this for empty : "tags" : null and then worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped.